# Structured data for Nobel Prizes

Tags: data-request, research, global

There is already a [Kaggle dataset (CSV)](https://www.kaggle.com/nobelfoundation/nobel-laureates#archive.csv) for Nobel Prize winners, but it hasn't been updated since 2016. Is there any up-to-date or official structured dataset for Nobel Prize winners?

The Kaggle columns are exactly what is needed.

```
Year
Category
Prize
Motivation
Prize Share
Laureate ID
Laureate Type
Full Name
Birth Date
Birth City
Birth Country
Sex
Organization Name
Organization City
Organization Country
Death Date
Death City
Death Country
```

For non-commercial purposes.

Comment: I haven't looked myself, but wikidata.org might help

Comment: yes, that would satisfy the "up-to-date" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the Kaggle page, there is an official API from nobelprize.org

https://nobelprize.readme.io/

With 3 endpoints:

```
Prize
getLaureate
getCountry
```

If you put in no parameters, with the "Try it out" section, you can get CSV or JSON outputs for the entire dataset.

Direct links to CSV:

- Prize: http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.csv
- Laureate: http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/laureate.csv
- Country: http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/country.csv

(Replace .csv with .json for that format.)