How to get a list of all Nobel Prize winners who never had a doctorate from Wikidata with SPARQL?
I'm trying to get a list of all Nobel Prize laureates who never had a doctorate from Wikidata.
I managed to fetch all the relevant data in the following query:
SELECT ?recipient ?recipientLabel ?awardLabel ?nobelDate ?educatedAtLabel ?academicDegree ?academicDegreeLabel ?educatedAtDate
WHERE {
  ?recipient wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ; # recepient is human (Peace prize can go to organizations) 
             p:P166 ?awardStat . # recepient was awarded something
  ?awardStat ps:P166 ?award .
  ?award wdt:P279* wd:Q7191 . # received any subclass of nobel prize (physics, chemistry, etc.) 
  ?awardStat pq:P585 ?nobelDate .
  ?recipient p:P69 ?recipientEducatedAt .
  ?recipientEducatedAt ps:P69 ?educatedAt .
  ?recipientEducatedAt pq:P512 ?academicDegree .
  ?academicDegree wdt:P279* wd:Q849697 . # degree is a doctorate
  OPTIONAL{ ?recipientEducatedAt pq:P582 ?educatedAtDate . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?nobelDate) ASC(?awardLabel)

but I don't know how to do the final filtering step.
I tried a few combinations of NOT IN and FILTER NOT EXISTS but I could not find the correct way.
The main difficulty is that without:
?academicDegree wdt:P279* wd:Q849697 . # degree is a doctorate

I get multiple lines for each laureate for different degrees they might have.
In SQL I'd want to use a NOT IN with a subquery, but I'm not sure how to do that in SPARQL.
The goal is to more algorithmically a answer questions such as:

https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/mv85av/has_anybody_without_a_phd_ever_won_the_nobel/
https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-ever-won-a-Nobel-Prize-without-a-PhD


I managed to craft the following query for it:
SELECT ?recipient ?recipientLabel ?awardLabel ?nobelDate # ?educatedAtLabel ?academicDegree ?academicDegreeLabel ?educatedAtDate
WHERE {
  ?recipient wdt:P31 wd:Q5 ; # recepient is human (Peace prize can go to organizations) 
             p:P166 ?awardStat . # recepient was awarded something
  ?awardStat ps:P166 ?award .
  ?award wdt:P279* wd:Q7191 . # received any subclass of nobel prize (physics, chemistry, etc.) Makes query faster.
  FILTER(?award IN (wd:Q44585, wd:Q38104, wd:Q80061)) # only consider the STEM Nobels: physics, chemistry and medicine
  ?awardStat pq:P585 ?nobelDate .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?recipient wdt:P512 ?academicDegree .
    ?academicDegree wdt:P279*/wdt:P31*/wdt:P279* wd:Q849697 . # degree is a doctorate
  }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?recipient wdt:P184 ?doctoralAdvisor }
  MINUS {
    ?recipient p:P69 ?recipientEducatedAt .
    ?recipientEducatedAt ps:P69 ?educatedAt .
    ?recipientEducatedAt pq:P512 ?educatedAtAcademicDegree .
    ?educatedAtAcademicDegree wdt:P279*/wdt:P31*/wdt:P279* wd:Q849697 . # degree is a doctorate
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?nobelDate) ASC(?awardLabel)

The trick to exclude educatedAt people was to use MINUS. I've also added a few more doctorate equivalents in use. I couldn't find any error on the query by clicking several of the results: the laureates don't appear to have any doctorate data on their wikidata.
Unfortunately almost all of them are false positives who actually have the PhD and just don't have the data in Wikidata. Wikipedia usually mentions their PhD, including in infoboxes for some of them. Maybe DBPedia would fare better in this case?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_Youyou seems to be correct. For the others, I did not find a WikiProject that caters to the area, so the most realistic option is to start filling the data into Wikidata. :-) I just did one.

@NicolasRaoul nice! Can you link to it, I don't know how those things work very well. I also found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guglielmo_Marconi on the query after quick incomplete inspection. All from https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/mv85av/has_anybody_without_a_phd_ever_won_the_nobel/  (including Tu) are also there, the problem is clearing missing educations of course.

@NicolasRaoul if you are particularly into nobel modeling this may also be of interest: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Project_chat#How_to_represent_fractions_e.g._to_say_which_proportion_of_the_Nobel_Prize_each_person_won_without_resorting_to_floating_point_numbers?

@NicolasRaoul one more, I also did a bit of Nobel place of birth curation at: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15750/structured-data-for-nobel-prizes/21847#21847 I found one that was wrong on the Nobel page which was funny.

Awards are not my area and I actually was unsure about the best structure, so mine might not be an example to follow. I would encourage contributors to write the opposite query (showing Nobels with a Phd) and checking how they are structured.
